# On an Apple 12W USB Charger, how are the D+ and D- lines configured?

Tags: usb, charger, iphone, ipad, apple

I'm looking for the voltages on the `D+` and `D-` lines of an Apple 12W charger that corresponds to the 2.4 A output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **D+** and **D-** lines must be held to **2.7 V** to support 12 W charging.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the Apple MFi Specification (which would be the best source), but [this forum entry](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/power_interface/f/204/t/295853) and subsequent answers by TI employees indicate that 2.7 V is the correct value.

Furthermore, this schematic below uses a resistor divider of 43.2k and 49.9k on the D+ and D- lines, which supports the TI forum responses of 2.7 V.

[image: ACT4523A 5V/2.4A iPad Car Charger]

This is the schematic of the ACT4523A 5V/2.4A iPad Car Charger (Page 13 of this [Analog Power Management Product Selection Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20161201195909/http://www.active-semi.com/sheets/ActiveSemi_Analog_Power_PSG_1Q2014.pdf), for your reference).

Answer (score 0):

After taking some measurements, a 2.4A charger from apple applies approximately 2.68VDC to both D+ and D-. Most usb chargers advertise compatibility/charge capability with a simple resistive voltage divider on the data lines. Just calculate the required divider to provide that voltage from Vbus, I would take your own measurements though... And be aware of potential damage to the consumer.